# MVCDonutCaching - how to remove Child action cache MVC Donut Caching

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, outputcache, donut-caching

I'm using this [MVCDonutCaching Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcDonutCaching/) because in the [tutorial](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3) they said this was possible with child actions.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466633/mvcdonutcaching-issues-with-child-action-when-parent-is-not-donut-cached) didn't work for me or I didn't understand it correctly.

If someone knows how to delete the child cache with the standard `OutputCache` attribute, then that is alright as well!

I've searched for this but I can't find it. See here an example:

Index action of the HomeController (homepage):

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```

ChildAction of the NewsController:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[ChildActionOnly]
[DonutOutputCache(Duration = 600, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
public PartialViewResult LastArticles(int numberOfArticles)
{
    return PartialView("_LastArticles", db.NewsArticles
    .Include(i => i.Tags)
    .Include(i => i.SeoTags)
    .Where(n => n.Status == PublishStatus.Published)
    .OrderByDescending(n => n.PublishDate)
    .Take(numberOfArticles)
    .ToList());
}
```

Index view of the HomeController:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("LastArticles", "News", new { numberOfArticles = 2 }); }
```

To clear the cache I have an **Admin** area in my application with a controller and action in it to update the data stored by the child action. So when a news article is updated. The cache should get refreshed on the homepage.

In that action I have the following code:

```
var cacheManager = new OutputCacheManager();
cacheManager.RemoveItem("News", "LastArticles", new { area = "", numberOfArticles = 2 });
cacheManager.RemoveItem("News", "LastArticles", new { area = "" });
```

I tried multiple versions but without luck. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Thanks to Marino: the solution is to use `cacheManager.RemoveItem("News", "LastArticles", new { numberOfArticles = 2 });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you shouldn't explicitly define the (empty) area. Although the area's an important part of the routing, MVCDonutCaching does something weird in defining an internal key. Perhaps MVCDonutCache has a bug concerning area's.

Comment: Your right! Deleting the empty area was the solution. Strange enough you must use the empty area if you use the standard `OutputCache`. Looks like a bug in the Nuget package.